# Give the ability to user to copy text in tkinter gui

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, tkinter

In this code when the user enters the link, a short version of the link get displayed but it does not give the ability to the user to copy the link from the GUI. How do i fix this?

```
import pyshorteners as pr
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()


def click():
    link = e.get()
    shortener = pr.Shortener()
    Short_Link = shortener.tinyurl.short(link)
    Label1 = Label(root, text=Short_Link)
    Label1.pack()


Button1 = Button(root, text="Enter link:", command=click)
Button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could use some button to copy text, or copy it automatically, or you can `bind` key `Ctrl+C` to window. or you can display it in `Entry` and then you can select text and use `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly copy the text from a Tkinter Label widget with CTRL+C.

This is a simple Tkinter app to copy the text of a Label to the clipboard:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


class CopyLabel(Tk):
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        super(CopyLabel, self).__init__()

        self.title('Copy this Label')

        self.label_text = text
        self.label = Label(self, text=text)
        self.label.pack(pady=10, padx=40)

        self.copy_button = Button(self, text='COPY TO CLIPBOARD', command=self.copy)
        self.copy_button.pack(pady=5, padx=40)

    def copy(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(self.label_text)

        self.update()

        showinfo(parent=self, message='Copied to clipboad!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CopyLabel('Copy me!')
    app.mainloop()
```

In your code to copy automatically the Short_Link you can do:

```
import pyshorteners as pr
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()


def click(master: Tk):
    link = e.get()
    shortener = pr.Shortener()
    Short_Link = shortener.tinyurl.short(link)
    master.clipboard_clear()
    master.clipboard_append(Short_Link)
    master.update()
    Label1 = Label(root, text=Short_Link)
    Label1.pack()

Button1 = Button(root, text="Enter link:", command=lambda: click(root))
Button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```